# Running junit4 tests as part of a junit5 dynamic test

Tags: junit, junit4, junit5

In junit5 you can create dynamic tests as in this code

```
 Stream<DynamicNode> dynamicTestsWithContainers() {
        return Stream.of("A", "B", "C")
            .map(input -> dynamicContainer("Container " + input, Stream.of(
                dynamicTest("not null", () -> assertNotNull(input)),
                dynamicContainer("properties", Stream.of(
                    dynamicTest("length > 0", () -> assertTrue(input.length() > 0)),
                    dynamicTest("not empty", () -> assertFalse(input.isEmpty()))
                ))
            )));
    }
```

I have loads of junit4 tests I don't want to migrate, but I could use them as subsets of tests that can be dynamically chained as part of a wider junit5 dynamic test.

Can this be done without recoding in a "streams way"? Can I wrap a junit4 test within a junit 5 dynamic test?

What I already tried:

- @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
- Executable (but not sure if there is a way to do it with this)

What I know:

- It would not be highly dynamic
- It may not be a best practice

Comment: Could you explain why you’d like to run JUnit 4 tests as dynamic tests and not just run them side by side with your JUnit 5 tests (which would be very easy)?

Comment: Because I want to run them as "subsets of tests that can be dynamically chained as part of a wider junit5 dynamic test."

Comment: OK. I don't really understand that sentence but it looks like you have a reason ;-)